# Will APC work with multiple versions of PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, alternative-php-cache

I have two versions of PHP running (5.2 & 5.3).  I would like to know how to install two separate versions of APC for PHP, or is that even necessary?  I can't find any info on alternative methods for installing APC other than a simple `pecl install apc`.

PHP 5.2 is compiled from source and PHP 5.3 is from the Debian repo.

Best!

Comment: What method are you using to get multiple versions?

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3 have different ABI (application binary interface) so 5.2 modules won't work on 5.3 and vice versa. You can install APC from source using the standard `phpize`, `./configure`, `make`, `make install` procedure. You should just use a proper `phpize` for your source-compiled PHP ver. 5.2